# ie8 and ie9 with jquery.form.js returns html instead of data echo from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

The thing I have to accomplish is to select my image file via an `<input type="file"...`
process it with a php script, resize the image and return the base64 value of the image echo in a string as a result of the php script. I have accomplish it already with Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer 10.

I'm using jquery.form.js to accomplish the same behaviour in ie8 and ie9 to do the ajax call to the php script and return data. The thing is that in this browsers the internet explorer 8-9 return an html (viewed from the console) as if the page was about to reload (as a usual php call behaves in ie8-9). I thing to notice is that no matter what the php does, it always return html, even if is as simple as:

```
<?php
   echo "Hello World";
?>
```

This is my scripts

HTML

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="%MYURL%" method="post">
        <input name="userImage" type="file" class="inputFile" id="inputFileID" size="43"  style="margin-right: 45px" />
        <input type="submit" id="save-data-image" unselectable="on" data-corner="tr bl 5px" rel="save" class="button tiny blue left" value="Save">
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('#uploadForm').ajaxForm(function(data) { 
      console.log("data:" + data);
});
```

So the goal is to return the "Hello World" string in IE8-9. I hope someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: and what is this html that you're getting back? PHP itself would never wrap your echo/print output in html. The only time it would output html without being told to is for error/warning messages.

Comment: It returns almost the same html as the page one, the same layout, as I put on the description it seems to be the html as if the page where to reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about how the inner workings of ajaxForm done, but I guess it uses an iframe to post the data and read the iframe back when the iframe loads. IE will force the returned string to be HTML by creating the "missing" <html> and <body> elements. You should tell IE not to parse it as an HTML by setting the Content-Type HTTP header to text/plain:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline;filename=File.txt');
    echo "Hello World";
?>
```

=== EDIT ===

Does not work! See https://github.com/malsup/form/issues/302 instead!

=== EDIT 2 ===

I've been messing around with this a bit more and I have this working.

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>UNTITLED</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//malsup.github.io/min/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#myForm").ajaxForm(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#myImg").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64, " + data);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="send.php" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="a" type="file">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<img id="myImg">
</body>
</html>
```

The PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html');
echo base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['a']['tmp_name']));
```

And it does render nicely in IE8 (not emulated). The only thing is, the image must not be larger than 4K as this is a limit in IE.

Comment: Hi, I've tried that, and instead of printing in console the data, it shows a pop-up saying "Do you want to open or save script.php", if I clicked open it opens a file which content some warnings and the image conveted to base64. Is there a way to get that info and avoid the pop-up to appear ?

Comment: Silly IE... Can you please try adding `header('Content-Disposition: inline;filename=File.txt');` after the header?

Comment: Download doesn't appear any more, but the data again is an html. Yeah Silly IE :p.

Comment: You can try making your response fully html. This issue on github is about the same problem: https://github.com/malsup/form/issues/302

Comment: Can you please check my new example code? See if that works? You need to select a png file no larger than 4K.

Comment: Is not working for me, what does your console prints??? Mine returns the html I mentioned. Thanks a lot for the help =) Do you have your IE in Document Mode IE8 standards ?

Comment: Here is a working example of the code I put in the answer: http://zenorbi.com/ajaxformtest/ If you see the non-html version, please compare the request and response headers to the version you're having problem with.

Comment: I copy exactly your code, and compare the request-response headers (in firebug) and we have the same ones. What else do you think it could be?

Comment: Could you pass me the link where you downloaded jquery.form.min.js please.

Comment: I seem to finf a work around to my problem, it seems that my master page of asp.net has some trouble with php. At the end I use this.
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>console.log('" . $image_info . "');</script>"; thanks a lot for the help, your answer is right.